# How long did it take Daedalus to build the Labyrinth

Tags: greek, theseus, daedalus, labyrinth

There may be no answer to this, as Greek mythology is full of inconsistent timelines, but is there any known indication of how long it took Daedalus to build the labyrinth?

Presuming Minos orders Daedalus to start building directly after the birth of Asterius (Asterion; the Minotaur), do we know how long it took to build something so vast?  Part of the reason I'm interested in this is that it elicits the question of what they did with Asterius in the interim.  Similarly, does Asterius have a known age?  He is imprisoned in the labyrinth for two cycles of the Great Year (either 7 or 9 years) before Theseus arrives on the third cycle and slaughters him.  Was he held elsewhere before this?  Presumably, Asterius is not an infant when the first cycle is sent from Athens, as he's capable of killing the 14 youths.

I know there is another theory that the Palace of Minos itself was the labyrinth, designed by Daedalus.  I like this theory, though it feels difficult to reconcile with the Theseus myth.  Out of curiosity, is there any indication of how long it took Daedalus to build the palace?

Thanks, and let me know if anything in my question is unclear.